# How to insert a determinant in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I want to insert a 3x3 determinant in MS Word but find any option for doing so under equations. I searched the web but could not find any site that deals with this. How do i insert a determinant in MS Word?

Comment: like this: "1"? - That's the determinant of the 3x3 identity matrix, for example.

Comment: @jvb, no. Not like that. That is the value of the determinant. I want insert a matrix like structure surrounded by two vertical lines, one on either side instead of square brackets.

Comment: I see. I've found this one (for 2x2, but with straight lines): Ctrl-F9 (to insert a field), then type `Eq \b\bc\|(\a\ar\co2(1; 3; 4; 2))`, Alt-F9 to close the field editor (or to re-open for editing). I guess co3 would be for 3x3?

Comment: @jvb, that is not working. The determinant that command produces has only one row.

Comment: please double-check your string, works with `co3` and nine values, too

Answer (score 3):

Open a new equation with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>, then type

```
A=|\matrix(0&0&0@0&0&0@0&0&0) |
```

and add space at the end.

Comment: Maybe I should be more precise: first, open a new equation with Alt + = then type A=|\matrix(0&0&0@0&0&0@0&0&0) |   and add space at the end.

Answer (score 2):

It expands like a table in Word.

1. Insert your 2x2 using the Equation Tools
2. Right-click on one of the 4 slots
3. Go to Insert
4. Click what you would like to add (row, col)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to find is to select **Equation** from the **Insert** tab, and select **Ink Equation** from the pulldown. This will open a new window in which you can use the mouse to "write" the equation, and it will attempt to "read" it and convert it to useful text, which you can then insert into your document.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a field like

[image: Word formula field, edit view]

will result in

[image]

(please ignore the thin line after the `ar`, apparently the cursor managed to get into the screenshot.)

Comment: Not coming on my computer.